# angularJs - Is it possible for 2 different models of different structures to sync or share states?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a list of checkboxes and values I"m loading from a list which comes back from the database.

Controller

```
listA = ['item1','item2'...'itemn']; //Master list of items
$scope.selectedItems = ["item1",... "item5"]; //selected items
$scope.attributesModel = [                 //new model based on selected items
    {"index":5,"attribute":"item1"},
    {"index":10, "attribute":"item2"},
    {"index":13, "attribute":"item3"},
    {"index":21, "attribute":"item4"},
    {"index":24, "attribute":"item5"}

];
```

View part 1

```
  <td>
      <div class="checkbox checkbox-notext">
        <input checklist-model="selectedItems" checklist-value="key" type="checkbox" id="{{key}}" ng-disabled="exceededLimit &amp;&amp; !checked" />
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <label for="{{key}}">{{key}}{{$index}}</label>
    </td>
```

view part 2

```
<div ng-repeat="(index, row) in attributesModel" >
<div class="margin10">
<div>Index<input ng-model="row.index" value="row.index" type="number" class="indexInputs"></input>{{row.attribute}}</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Now I would like to sync $scope.selectedItems and $scope.attributesModel. When a checkbox is deselected, both selectedItems and attributesModel models remove that item, and vice versa. So every time someone checks a new checkbox they are presented a attributesModel with an empty text field to type the index value.

**catch** The index key is null initially for every newly selected item that is added to attributesModel. The user must enter a new index # once the new item is created.

I've tried using watch but the problem I run into is when a new item is selected, I don't have access to the item itself. I only have access to the list without any idea whether the new item is X or if the item removed is Y in order to push/delete the right item.

So this might be a watch solution that I'm missing.

Let me know if I can clarify anything.

Comment: The $watch listener is called with 3 arguments, (newValue, oldValue, scope), Perhaps you could compare the oldValue to the newValue to determine which item need to be pushed/spliced?

Comment: @JonathanGawrych How can I watch an individual item in the list though? If I watch the list, newValue and oldValue are just the entire list with no clue as to which item was removed (unless I iterate the list). Is there a way to watch an individual item in the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what the problem is, but you could use `ngChange` on the checkboxes:

```
<input type="checkbox" ... ng-change="..." />
```

I asdume you have a checklist directive or something, so should do something there, but (since you don't share it with us) I can't tell what exactly :)

---

**UPDATE:**

Since the `checklist` directive is an external dependency, you could handle the ng-chage in your code:

```
<input type="checkbox" ... ng-change="changed(key)" />

/* In the controller: */
...
$scope.changed = function (key) {
    if ($scope.selectedItems.indexOf(key) === -1) {
        // The checkbox for `key` was unchecked...
    } else {
        // The checkbox for `key` was checked...
    }
};
```

Comment: I'm using the checklist directive from here http://vitalets.github.io/checklist-model/

Comment: @EKet: I thought it was yur directive. Take a look at my updated answer.